# Why are locations deleted when an event that uses them is deleted?

Tags: civievent, location

If you delete an event and that event is the only one that uses a particular location, then the location is deleted as well.

If you then want to use that location for another event, you have to recreate it - seems a bit unnecessary?

or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

well after a bit of experimenting the answer is.. they just are.

Here's a workaround that worked for me.

1 create new location type "location only"
2 make new events of type "location only" and give the title the same as the location you want to manage eg if the location is "Town Hall" then the name of the event will be "Location Town Hall" and the venue will be "Town Hall"

now it doesn't matter what happens with other events that might have used "Town Hall" as their location.. "Town Hall" will survive

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first question is: why are you deleting events?  If they are test events, then the locations are likely to be test ones as well.  If they are real events with participants then typically you want to retain the information about the event and its participants and contributions etc.

Since events are rarely deleted this seems like a non-issue. If event locations are the locations where you have held events, it makes sense for the location to be removed if there is no event associated with it. Do you have a particular workflow/set of requirements that involves regularly deleting events?